# Can you recognise this motorcycle?

Tags: motorcycle, design

[image]

Can you recognise this motorcycle?

Comment: I believe it's an Indian, but I couldn't tell you what year/model it would be. Maybe @DucatiKiller or Jonathan Musso will be on here and help.

Comment: It is nice.  Wish I could figure it out.

Answer (score 8):

I believe it's a '41(?) Harley Flathead.

[image: 41 flathead]

Answer (score 3):

I believe it's a Harley WLD from 1941 or '42. It is clearly their 740 cc engine

Comment: This might help...Harley Museum pic of the '41 in the same position... https://www.harley-davidson.com/content/dam/h-d/images/museum/explore/h-d-history/en_US/1941-2.jpg